# Multiple configurations with different locations (React App) at the same domain using Nginx

Tags: django, reactjs, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config

I'm trying to configure Nginx for 2 different locations. 
This is my scenario.

```
www.example.com 
location : /var/www/example.com

example.com/panel 
location : /var/www/example.com/panel
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files

```
location ^~ /root {
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
location ^~ /root/react_app(or panel) {
    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /root/react_app/index.html;
}
```